# Jquery: sanitizing all the html tags except <br>

Tags: html, jquery

I'm using the following function to sanitize the inputs:

```
function sanStr(str) {
     return str.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
           .replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;");}
```

How can I edit this code block so that it replaces all the HTML tags with their equivalents except `<br>` tag? I don't want it to replace break lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify), which is highly configurable, and much safer.

Comment: You *could* replace `<br>` with something that is *unlikely* to occur in your str, then replace it back after your other replacements.  There's always the risk that whatever you choose will be in the str.  As an example: `str.replace(/<br>/g, "@###@").replace(...)).replace(/@###@/, "<br/>")`

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest replacing it by the equivalent **\n**

```js
let regexLineBreak = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
return str.replace(regexLineBreak, "\n")
```

You can check with this fiddle

```js
function sanitizeThisText() {
  var str = $("#text").val();
  var sanitizedStr = sanStr(str);
  $("#text").val(sanitizedStr);
}

function sanStr(str) {
  var regexLineBreak = /<br\s*[\/]?>/gi;
  return str.replace(regexLineBreak, "\n").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
    .replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text">
  Neque porro quisquam
  <br/>
  est qui dolorem
</textarea>
<button onclick="sanitizeThisText()">Sanitize</button>
```